# Analyst Forecasts for monthly unemployment rate

Tags: statistics, research, market-data

Are there any resources that tabulate past analyst forecasts for the monthly unemployment rate along with the dispersion of the forecasts

Answer (score 1):

Haver analytics has this data, though its not cheap